# How does Windows associate icons to files in explorer shell?

Tags: windows, icons, detection, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I have both InDesign CS2 and CS3 installed. Both use files with .indd extension. How does Windows know which icon to use? It uses correct icons i.e. CS2 files have cs2 icon and CS3 files have CS3 icon.

How does Windows know how to do this?

And how can I extract or use this version-detection system in my programs?

**Edit:**

Thank you for your shell-extension-icon-handler answers. Something new to me. But is there any way I could connect to IconHandler that InDesign provides and use it to detect version of the InDesign file?

Comment: It's unlikely you'd be able to get that information from InDesign's handler.  However, it's worth seeing if there are any other shell extensions registered for that file type, eg it might implement the property interface which could give you that value.  Try right-clicking to get file properties and check the Details tab.

I would try loading the cs2 and cs3 files into a hex editor and look at the first 20 bytes or so.  In many file formats the header is common, and contains a version number (which won't necessarily be 2 or 3), so you may be able to identify from just that.

Comment: @the_mandrill that is what I was doing reading first bytes. But the version information is not fixed, it floats sometimes. That's why I'm looking for more reliable method, if available.

Comment: In that case, you probably won't be able to do it unless the file format has been published or reverse-engineered.  One possibility could be to invoke Adobe's icon handler and then detect which icon has been used, but this may be unreliable and of course requires that the handler has been installed on the system (which you may not be able to guarantee and you won't be able to redistribute it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write an Icon Handler shell extension.  See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122(VS.85).aspx) documentation for `IExtractIcon`.  The basic mechanism is that you create a shell extension and register the icon handler for the file type you want (look in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.indd) and then the shell loads your handler, passes the file information and requests an icon in return.  There's also the [IExtractImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761848%28VS.85%29.aspx) method if you want to provide a thumbnail bitmap rather than just an icon.

Note that you need to be especially careful writing shell extension handlers as any memory leaks or crashes can nuke the explorer and any other applications that display a file open/save dialog.

Comment: Ok you answered first part of my question. The other part is probably impossible.

Answer (score 2):

For some files it's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file extension here>\DefaultIcon` registry entry, but most files map to a more friendly name, e.g. `.pdf\(Default)` -> `AcroExch.Document` (if Adobe Reader is installed).

In that case you have to go along the registry to `AcroExch.Document` and see that either

- `DefaultIcon` is right there *or*
- `AcroExch.Document\CLSID\(Default)` is some GUID. Then, follow `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<insert that guid here>` and you'll notice that this key contains `DefaultIcon`

... and `DefaultIcon` is where the icon is loaded from.

Hope that was clear enough ;). I don't know about your special case but there should be a distinction in the registry.

Comment: That's the case for a fixed icon, but the OP was asking about how to switch the icon type programmatically when you have two versions of a file but with the same extension.  +1 though for mentioning about having to do a second level of indirection on the GUID

Answer (score 1):

It almost certainly installs a [shell icon extension handler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide9.aspx).  Writing your own *and* knowing how to detect the version in a file format that isn't documented well or at all is quite tricky.

Comment: can you provide a link to a project that support windows 7 and not just xp?